# How to change LaTeX Font Style?

Tags: fonts

How do I change the font in LaTeX?

I want to create font that looks like this:

[image: Good Font]

but TeXShop gives me this font:

[image: Bad Font]

How do I can make the font in the bottom image look like the font in the top image? The text looks a bit thicker and darker than the first text.

The second paragraph was produced by:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ left = 23mm, right  = 23mm, top = 24mm, bottom = 24mm ] {geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, mathptmx}
\usepackage{pstricks, pst-node, pst-plot, pst-circ}
\usepackage{moredefs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\interlinepenalty=10000

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\noindent
This is a simple and traditional approach involving storage of the piece positions, in 
a 64-bit word, to represent each of the 64 positions on the chess board. Representing a 
piece on the board implies turning on that bit. There are 12 bit-boards to encode the 
6 white and 6 black pieces (king, queen, rook, bishop, knight, pawn). Figure 2.6 
illustrates the bit-board of the white queen corresponding to the position h5.
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The size? The spacing? The coloured link after figure?

Comment: The font style, not the spacing or the colour.

Comment: How do you compile your document? How is the first picture generated, and can you provide an MWE that shows us how the second picture is generated? Both fonts appear to be `Computer Modern`, are perhaps using bold fontstyle?

Comment: @Jörg The second one is definitely not CM, compare e, T, or any of the digits. @ KillaKem, please post the code you’re using to produce the second example.

Comment: The second is Times. Not surprisingly, given mathptmx is loaded.

Comment: Substitute `\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, mathptmx}` with `\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, lmodern}`

Comment: @doncherry Yes, my eyesight is apparently not what it used to be...

Comment: @Jörg, would you care to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CW from the comments:

Instead of

```
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, mathptmx}
```

(`mathptmx` is a Times clone), use

```
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, lmodern}
```

(`lmodern` is an updated Computer Modern).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, lmodern}

\begin{document}
\noindent This is a simple and traditional approach involving storage of the piece positions, in 
a 64-bit word, to represent each of the 64 positions on the chess board. Representing a 
piece on the board implies turning on that bit. There are 12 bit-boards to encode the 
6 white and 6 black pieces (king, queen, rook, bishop, knight, pawn). Figure 2.6 
illustrates the bit-board of the white queen corresponding to the position h5.
\end{document}
```

[image]